# switching from a photo background to a plain background for mobile devices

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm relatively new to coding websites, and I'm building my first responsive, bootstrap based site. Specifically, on large displays, I have fullscreen photo backgrounds, but for mobile devices I want to just have a plain colour background. All the answers I've found are for changing one photo for another.
the closest answer I found was this (for changing the image):

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    background-image: url(../images/bg-mobile.png);
}
```

Could I just substitute the image url for a plain background colour?

Thanks

Gregg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the background-image to none and then add a background colour for that break point. For example:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
   .head {
      background-image: none;
      background: pink;
   }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I'm not at my laptop to test it out, But forewarned is forearmed as they say! I have coded sites in the past, but this is the first one I really want to be responsive, and when I have tested it at smaller screen sizes it doesn't look good having images for the background. Thanks again